# Can't delete file after copy

Tags: c#, file, io

An unhandled exception of type `System.IO.IOException` occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the file `pathOfMyFile` because it is being used by another process.

This is the error I get when reaching `File.Delete`
My code looks like this:

```
File.Copy(frompath, topath1);
File.Copy(frompath, topath2);
System.GC.Collect();
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
File.Delete(frompath);
```

`frompath` is a path to a .png image.
What can I do to make this work?

Comment: `topath1`, `topath2` and `topath` are three different variables. Your application, or another application, still holds a lock on the file pointed to by `topath`. Show all relevant code.

Comment: Did you mean to delete *frompath*? I'm assuming you aren't trying to copy  a file just to turn around and delete the copy you just made.

Comment: Yes, i've miswritten it

Comment: Can you share some more relevant details and your prior research in your question? What else do you do with the file in `frompath`? [Do you have a virus scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603444/file-copy-locks-source-file-after-completion)? Who holds the lock according to a tool that can tell you this, like Unlocker?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a brand new program? E.g., you put this into a new console app, give it a path, and it fails? Also you say, "can't delete *after* copy." Are you saying if you remove the two File.Copy lines then you *can* delete?

Comment: there isnt enough code to determine what could the possible error. I presume the file is not closed so there fore cannot be deleted. Try File.Create(frompath).Close() before doing File.Delete

Comment: Yes, i have Kaspersky Internet Security 2016. Tried disabling protection, but the error still occurs.

Comment: Code doesn't work if i comment out the copy lines.... now i'll check in console

Answer (score 0):

First you can remove the two garbage collection calls as they will be processed automatically.

If the copy is simply taking time to complete and the file system to release the handle, you can attempt repeated deletes until it works.  You could ignore IOExceptions but make sure to handle other types.

```
while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(50);

    try
    {
        File.Delete(frompath);
        break;
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        // Ignore IO exceptions
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Handle other exceptions
    }
}
```

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/2186775/2131092 the main thread is blocked by File.Copy until the copy completes. So it shouldn't be the copy process that is locking the file.